# Search for a string from a textbox in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Button – calls a function to determine if
the string in the textbox is found in the contents of the textarea. Naturally,
message to the user if the string was found or not.

Those were the instructions given to follow, Im not sure exactly how to do this. Here is what I came up with, I keep getting this console error:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>    file:///........program02javascript/program02script.js
>   Line 10
>
> line 10 : var SearchTerm = document.getElementById("text_box_1").value;

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="requirement #2">
    <h1>Requirement #2</h1>
    <form>
        Search For:
        <input type="text" name="text_box_1">
        <br>
    </form>
    <textarea id="text_area_3"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="button2" onclick="StringSearch()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
function StringSearch() {
    var SearchTerm = document.getElementById("text_box_1").value;
    var TextSearch = document.getElementById("text_area_3").value;

    if (TextSearch.match(SearchTerm) === "") {
        alert("String Found. Search Complete");
    } else {
        alert("No Data found in Text Area");
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this task? I'm not sure I understand completely what to do. I was trying to find some example code but haven't come across anything that's been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You haven't added `id` to the element, `getElementById` selects the element from DOM based on the value of `id` attribute not the `name` attribute.

   Add the `id` attribute to the textbox

   ```
   Search For:<input type="text" name="text_box_1" id="text_box_1"><br>
   //                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. You're using `match()` to check if the match is found, but you can use `indexOf` to check if the string is present in another.
3. Add validation if the user has entered anything to search, if not return.

**Demo**

```js
function StringSearch() {
  var SearchTerm = document.getElementById("text_box_1").value;
  var TextSearch = document.getElementById("text_area_3").value;

  if (SearchTerm.length > 0 && TextSearch.indexOf(SearchTerm) > -1) {
    alert("String Found. Search Complete");
  } else {
    alert("No Data found in Text Area");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="requirement #2">
  <h1>Requirement #2</h1>
  <form>
    Search For:
    <input type="text" name="text_box_1" id="text_box_1">
    <br>
  </form>
  <textarea id="text_area_3"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="button2" onclick="StringSearch()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: mmm ok, thanks alot! If I wanted to display say the sentence in which it was found or in some manner that shows where it was found... how would I go about doing that? is it simply adding a few more lines of code, or would you have to go about it in a completly different manner?

Comment: @kronis72 When you use `indexOf()`, you'll get the index of the word where match is found, you can use this index to extract sentence/word

Comment: can we highlight the found keyword on textarea? How ?Thanks

Comment: If anyone is still looking how to highlight found keyword on textarea, here is the working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793518/how-to-select-a-word-or-a-phrase-in-a-text-area-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
function StringSearch() {
  var SearchTerm = document.getElementById("text_box_1").value;
  var TextSearch = document.getElementById("text_area_3").value;

  if (SearchTerm.length > 0 && TextSearch.indexOf(SearchTerm) > -1) {
    alert("String Found. Search Complete");
  } else {
    alert("No Data found in Text Area");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="requirement #2">
  <h1>Requirement #2</h1>
  <form>
    Search For:
    <input type="text" name="text_box_1" id="text_box_1">
    <br>
  </form>
  <textarea id="text_area_3"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="button2" onclick="StringSearch()">Search</button>
</div>
```